# how to seperate user acess to database in mongodb/mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

On the web app, I am currently working on, there is a button a user can click which will store emails into my `MongoDB` database. I also have a button where the user can click after they select a time range that displays all of the messages that are stored in the database for that time. The problem I am having is that when different users log in, they are able to see the other users messages when they click that button that retrieves the messages.

I am trying to figure out how can I make it so that a user can only see the messages that they have stored and not someone else's. Any ideas will be great.

`report_schema`

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')

var sera = mongoose.Schema({
    isRead: Boolean,
    subject: String,
    from: String,
    receivedDateTime: Date,
    sentDateTime: Date
});

var user = mongoose.Schema({
    userID: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        userName: String,
        ref: 'SERA'
    }
});


module.exports = mongoose.model("SERA", sera)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to create another collection which contains user details and add a reference into below code to identify the user:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')

var sera = mongoose.Schema({
    isRead: Boolean,
    subject: String,
    from: String,
    receivedDateTime: Date,
    sentDateTime: Date,
    user: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}      <-- this line
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("SERA", sera)
```

Comment: what does `ref: 'User'` mean?

Comment: It would refer another schema which contains user details. It would help to identify the user. Link to documentation: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: see above changes. Is this how? @Simon Thiel

Comment: The schema sera would ref the schema user direct instead of the other way around

Comment: @moegizzle, do you require any further clarification?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Will go ahead and mark them as the correct answer. Can I reach out for any other questions related to this?

Comment: @moegizzle, of course! Feel free to reach out to me related mongoose specific topics.